# Javascript passes function and receives error: Uncaught TypeError, process is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code runs fine.  My IDE (RubyMine) sees no problem with it.  But Chrome DevTools throws an error both in the Source and in the Console.  Is there some way to clean this up?

```
Uncaught TypeError: process is not a function

$(document).ready(function () {
    let buttonWatch = function (process) {
        $(this).off('click');
        alert(typeof(process)); // This alerts "function"
        process();              // The error is thrown here
        return $(this).on('click', buttonWatch);
    };
    $("#loginButton").on('click', function () {
        function process() {
            alert("Running a process.");
        }
        buttonWatch(process);
    });
});
```

Revised code as recommended shows same issues:

```
let myProcess;
let process;
$(document).ready(function () {

    let buttonWatch = function (process) {
        $(this).off('click');
        alert(typeof(process));  // alerts "function"
        process();               // Error thrown here
        return $(this).on('click', buttonWatch);
    };

    $("#loginButton").on('click', function () {
        function myProcess() {
            alert("Running a process.");
        }
        buttonWatch(myProcess);
    });

});
```

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu  It actually does work as coded, only Chrome DevTools complains.  The return only reinstantiates the click listener and does not redefine the function at all.

Comment: I've played some more with it and re-revised my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu  I do appreciate your help and advice.  It helped me come to a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I repeatedly stated, the code runs fine.  I only get the weird error from DevTools.  In any case, the error is eliminated by using an assignment and DevTools is happy.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let buttonWatch = function (process) {
        $(this).off('click');
        alert(typeof(process)); // This alerts "function"
        let result = process(); // No error is thrown
        return $(this).on('click', buttonWatch);
    };
    $("#loginButton").on('click', function () {
        function process() {
            alert("Running a process.");
        }
        buttonWatch(process);
    });
});
```

The issue here is that, because the click listener must be reinstantiated upon return, I cannot return the result of the process.  So, I coded a better solution using disabled instead of offing the listener at all.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    let buttonWatch = function (button, process) {
        $(button).prop("disabled", true);
        let result = process();
        $(button).prop("disabled", false);
        return result;
    };
    $("#loginButton").on('click', function () {
        function buttonProcess() {
            alert("Running a process.");
        }
        buttonWatch(this, buttonProcess);
    });
});
```

Just for completeness, this set up can be used when passing parameters and requiring that return of the process's results:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // buttonWatch disables and enables clicks around a process
    let buttonWatch = function (button, process) {
        $(button).prop("disabled", true);
        let result = process();
        $(button).prop("disabled", false);
        return result;
    };
    $("#loginButton").on('click', function () {
        function buttonProcess(message) {
            alert(message);
            return false
        }
        buttonWatch(this, function(){return buttonProcess("Running a process.")});
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working for me in either Firefox or Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/0xe01mgx/

Comment: If the purpose of your code is to prevent your function to be executed twice on double-clicks, you should probably look at `debounce`. And you might want to start giving hints about the functionality of your code in your questions, just in case there are better ways to do what you want to do.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu  I had incorrect coding on the prop disabled settings.  It's been revised.  I'll look at debounce.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error when you add on click event on button dynamically within event process itself. So you are trying to take off click event, do some processing and then add the event back. But problem is when you add event handler back to your button click, you are not passing the process function on this line.

```
return $(this).on('click', buttonWatch);
```

So you need to make couple of changes.

1. Make your function available outside of click event scope
2. Bind process function as parameter to buttonWatch method when you add on

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
    let buttonWatch = function (process) {
        $(this).off('click');
        alert(typeof(process)); // This alerts "function"
        process();              // The error is thrown here
        return $(this).on('click', buttonWatch.bind(this,process));
    };
    
    $("#loginButton").on('click', function () {
        function process () {
            alert("Running a process.");
        }
        buttonWatch(process);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
</html>
```

Reference : [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: The buttonWatch code is a generic function that prevents doubleclicks.  The process function is specific to each button.  So, that process function is created within the scope of the listener.  There is no problem with the code as written, as it operates correctly many times.  The only issue is DevTools false identification of an error.  I resolved that by making it an assignment.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve it. If process function needs to be dynamic, you can bind the parameter function. Updating answer.